# Detecting connection reset in firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

is there a way to detect "problem loading page" in firefox? i'd like to be able to know that the page load has failed and automatically reload the page. i'd also like to have a timed allowance for a page to load before the browser tries to reload it. i think this can be done by writing an add-on for firefox, but before i learn how to do that i want to know if it's even possible. all of the paths i have researched have only led me to things that are possible after the page has loaded. in this case the connection is aborted due to high traffic on the site requested and the page never loads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [progress listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Progress_Listeners). When a page finishes loading the `onStateChange` method of your progress listener will be called with `STATE_STOP` and `STATE_IS_WINDOW` flags set. You can check `aStatus` parameter then. For example, for a "connection reset" error it will have the value `Components.results.NS_ERROR_NET_RESET`.

See also:
[Network error codes](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/base/public/nsNetError.h)

Comment: @user1196661: Feel free to accept the answer then: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask